# Кракозябры при печати при попытке токенизировать текст на русском языке

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, data-mining

помогите найти пакет для токенизации русского текста. вот где уперся.

Входные данные:любой русский текст.

На выходе выдает нечто вроде:

```
S
  Ďî÷ňč/JJ
  äîńňčăíóň/NNP
  óđîâĺíü/NNP
  ďđîřëîăî/NNP
  ăîäŕ/NNP
  ďî/NNP
  đîńňó/NNP
  đĺŕëüíűő/NNP
  đŕńďîëŕăŕĺěűő/NNP
  äĺíĺćíűő/NNP
  äîőîäîâ/NNP
  íŕńĺëĺíč˙/NNP
  (/(...........
```

То есть какие-то теги он расставляет, но кодировка побита и теги явно расставлены неправильно( во входном тексте просто нет такого кол-ва NNP)

```
import pandas as pd
import pymysql
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import state_union
from nltk.tokenize import PunktSentenceTokenizer

nltk.download('russian')
con = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='',
                      database='parser', charset='utf8')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM comments ", con)
df['comm'][0].lstrip()


def delete_tabs(str):
    str = str.lstrip()
    str = str.rstrip()
    return str


comm = df['comm'].apply(delete_tabs)

train_text = state_union.raw('comm.txt')
sample_text = state_union.raw('comm.txt')

custom_sent_tokenizer = PunktSentenceTokenizer(train_text)

tokenized = custom_sent_tokenizer.tokenize(sample_text)


def process_content():
    try:
        for i in tokenized[5:]:
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(i)
            tagged = nltk.pos_tag(words)

            namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary=True)
            print(namedEnt)
            # namedEnt.draw()

except Exception as e:
print(str(e))
process_content()
```

Comment: Не совсем понятно (если не вчитываться глубоко в код), где именно вы уперлись. Верно ли я понимаю, что вы используете `nltk.tokenize.PunktSentenceTokenizer`, но он не дает желаемый результат с текстом на русском языке (или в кириллице?) и вы ищете решение, которое даст результат?

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста 1) небольшой пример входных данных, 2) желаемый результат и 3) фактический результат. Пока что не очевидно, что там фактически получается — программа выбрасывает исключение или не распознает текст или ...

Comment: @NickVolynkin 
добавил, гляньте, если не сложно.

Comment: Ага, так вроде стало понятнее. Поправил форматирование немного.

Comment: Попробуйте локализировать проблему. К примеру, если при печати данных из pd.read_sql() вы уже искажённые данные получаете, то остальной код следует убрать и начать выяснять в чём проблема: каждое место где байты а Unicode или обратно преобразуются следует проверить. Начните с `print('\u0430\u0431\u0432')` — если это уже кракозябры показывает, то остальной код не нужен  [mcve]